# Scrapy view and requests.get difference for "https://www.mywebsite.com.sg"

Tags: scrapy, python-requests, response

I am trying to scrape https://www.mywebsite.com.sg but the following command returns 400 bad request error:

`scrapy view https://www.mywebsite.com.sg`

If I use:

```
data=requests.get("https://www.mywebsite.com.sg")
```

I can get the content of the webpage in `data.text` and `data.content`.

However all the xpath operations in my script dotn't work as `data.xpath` and `data.content` are both empty.

There seems to be no protection in the webpage as `postman` software can get result with a simple HTTP GET query.

How do I get the response object to be properly filled?

Comment: Scraping sites is an art, not a science. Unfortunately, no one is going to investigate tghis for you and give you a solution. Your best bet is to research further and come back when you have a specific question about why this site is resisting being scraped. Always provide a [mcve] if you do, along with some sample output.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us which URL you are trying to scrape?

Comment: Thanks I am trying to scrape https://www.watsons.com.sg

Comment: Just can't figure out why request is ok but not scrapy view.